# Why are the %al register and stack modified before calling printf x86 assembly from C "Hello World" program compiled by gcc

Tags: c, x86, x86-64

I am trying to better understand compilers and assembly and am currently trying to understand why this simple "Hello, World" program modifies the stack and %al registers before calling printf.

This is the assembly generated by gcc with optimization off (some compiler directives have been removed):

```
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   _printf
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)          ## 4-byte Spill
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ## -- End function
    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:                                 ## @.str
    .asciz  "Hello, World!\n"
```

And here is the (extremely simple) C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello, World!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I am wondering specifically what is going on in the two lines preceding the "call _printf" instruction. It seems that part of the stack is zeroed out and the %al register as well, but I have no idea why.

I am also confused about why the %ecx register is cleared and filled with the contents of %eax, which I assume is the return value from printf, before returning.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Calling convention for variadic functions on amd64 says that `%al` contains the number of SIMD registers that need to be saved.

Comment: On top of o11c's comment: Compile code with `-O3` to remove a lot of the noise from the generated code. You are compiling with no optimizations so there are unnecessary loads and stores.

Comment: Also, I think you're getting confused by the AT&T vs Intel syntax thing. %ecx is zeroed and then copied *to* %eax, which is probably related to register-renaming and out-of-order execution.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thank you that helps.

Comment: @o11c thank you, I was confused because the ASM is in AT&T but I also had radare2 open with it in Intel so I misread it. So would a different number be in %al if I were using non callee-saved registers?

Comment: No, `%al` is nonzero whenever you pass floating-point arguments, which the CC requires to go in `%xmm0`, etc.

Comment: You can find a lot more information in https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing `%ecx` and transferring it to `%eax` just ensures that the main function returns 0. Just before that, the return value of the `_printf` function is copied from `%eax` to the stack frame with `movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)`, but this value is simply discarded as the stack begins to deallocate the frame with the `addq    $16, %rsp` instruction.